# Не видны обновления файлов после копирования на сетевой накопитель

Tags: smb, nfs

есть такая проблема:
дано условно n-количество ПК и сетевой накопитель.
ПК1 делает запись логов работы программы на свой жёсткий диск. На нём же запущен скрипт который раз в несколько секунд делает копию файлов на сетевой накопитель, на других ПК которые открывают этот сетевой накопитель, обновления файлов бывают происходят и всё работает нормально, а бывает не происходят, как будто ничего не копируется, НО если зайти в папку сетевого накопителя куда копируются файлы через ПК1, в течении примерно 1 секунды видно старый размер файлов, а после этого их состояние обновляется и появляется новый обновлённый размер файлов и только после этих действий на других ПК также становится видно что файлы обновились.

данная проблема была замечена при копировании в разных вариациях ПК1 и сетевых накопителях:

1. ПК1-windows подключен к сетевому накопителю по smb, копирование через bat скрипт с командой robocopy /e /mt /dcopy:DAT который в цикле раз в 5 секунд вызывает её
2. ПК1-astralinux подключенному к сетевому накопителю по nfs через обычное монтирование каталога, копирование через скрипт bash командой cp -rvuT раз в 3 секунды.

В чём вообще может быть проблема? В каком направлении искать?